# Can I only set one icon in android for all the dpis?

Tags: android, icons

So im creating a new app and I was wondering if i could only make one icon(technically two but one is 512*512 for the play store). So ill just make a max size icon for xxhdpi will lower res phones scale correctly, or would i actually have to make one for each dpi level. If that is the case, are there any tools that creates the different sizes for me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to make one for each screen density. There are tools available to assist you in this: http://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/index.html

Answer (score 0):

You really have to have an icon for each density value, otherwise you will have a 512*512 icon being used in a ldpi phone, which is very inefficient, as for ldpi phones you should use a 32x32 icon instead. Just use an image editor and resize your original icon or use on-line tools to resize it for you. ynnadkrap has a good example of a tool you can use to get your icons.